# React (Native): Pass a prop with the value obtained from an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working with React Native.

I want to pass a prop from a component (`Father` in this example) to its child. The value of such prop should be a string and I want to encapsulate the logic that calculates the value of such string in a function (`favoriteIconHandler` in this example).

But I can't manage to pass the string returned by the function `favoriteIconHandler`. I allways seem to pass either a function or an object, thus generating this message:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `name` of value `function proxiedMethod() {
    [native code]
}` supplied to `Icon`, expected one of ["3d-rotation","ac-unit",
```

This is the code that I'm working with:

```
export default class Father extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.favoriteIconHandler = this.favoriteIconHandler.bind(this);
    }

    async favoriteIconHandler (name) {
        let isFavorite = false;
        try {
            const favorites = await AsyncStorage.getItem('favorites') || 'none';
            isFavorite = favorites.includes(name);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
        }

        let icon = 'star-border';
        if (isFavorite) icon = 'star';
        return icon
    };

    render() {
        // ...
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                    <DetailListItem
                        icon={this.favoriteIconHandler(name)} // this function call is not working as expected
                    />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

So my question is, how should I call the `favoriteIconHandler` function in order to obtain the string it returns and pass it as a prop?

Comment: ` icon={this.favoriteIconHandler(name)}` where is name defined?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `favoriteIconHandler()` method is an `async` function, it is returning a `Promise`, so your `<DetailListItem>` basically looks like this:

```
<DetailListItem icon={Promise.resolve()} />
```

What you can do is using the component state to pass a default value, and when the promise resolves, then you update it:

```
export default class Father extends React.Component {
  state = { icon: 'star-border' }

  componentDidMount() {
    await favoriteIconHandler(); // pass a name here?
  }

  async favoriteIconHandler (name) {
    try {
      const favorites = await AsyncStorage.getItem('favorites') || 'none';

      favorites.includes(name) && this.setState(() => ({
        icon: 'star',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { icon } = this.state;

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          <DetailListItem icon={icon} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with how this is setup.

As per [javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), an async function must be called with an `await` in front of it. How you have it now, you asking an async function to go, but you're not waiting for it to finish. **However I'm not even confident that changning that will work.**

The better solution would be to pass the function itself as a prop. IE adding a prop to `detailListItem` called something like `iconGetterFunction={this.favoriteIconHandler}`. Then in the `detailListItem` component's `componentDidMount` or something you can call

```
let result = await props.iconGetterFunction()
```

At this point, use the result as you would.